# Spring MVC and Virtual Host Handling

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, tomcat, spring-mvc

I have written an application with Spring MVC and Tomcat, right now for example if the user Alice want to see John page she enters this :

> http://dns-name.com:8080/projectName/John

I fetch the last octet "John" in my application using Spring **@PathVariable** and request to Database for rendering John page .

however using **@PathVariable** Spring annotation,I just can fetch the octect "after" **projectName** restfully!

```
@RequestMapping(value="{user}")
public String renderUserPage(@PathVariable("user") String username, .... )
```

Can I have a config like this in tomcat :

> ```
> <Host name="*.dns-name.com:8080" appBase="webapps">
> ```

till it forward all the wildcard requests to me and then fetch the wildcard String name "John" ex:

> http://John.dns-name.com:8080/projectName

using Spring MVC ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Spring MVC supports hostname matching.

You can take a look at an independent project, [springmvc-router](https://github.com/resthub/springmvc-router).

Comment: I think, we can do this using interceptors but I don't know how to do it !